# Stack Overflow issue, Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, stack-overflow

I am getting "System.StackOverflowException was unhandled" on public

```
VolunteerDBEntities() : base("name=VolunteerDBEntities", "VolunteerDBEntities")
        {
            OnContextCreated();
        }
```

It happens when I change this:

```
   public class OrganizationService : IOrganizationService
    {

        private IValidationDictionary _validationDictionary;
        private IOrganizationRepository _repository;

        public OrganizationService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
            : this(validationDictionary, new OrganizationRepository())
        { }


        public OrganizationService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary, IOrganizationRepository repository)
        {
            _validationDictionary = validationDictionary;
            _repository = repository;
        }
...}
```

To this:

```
public class OrganizationService : IOrganizationService
    {

        private IValidationDictionary _validationDictionary;
        private IOrganizationRepository _repository;
        private ISessionService _session;

        public OrganizationService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
            : this(validationDictionary, new OrganizationRepository(), new SessionService())
        { }


        public OrganizationService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary, IOrganizationRepository repository, ISessionService session)
        {
            _validationDictionary = validationDictionary;
            _repository = repository;
            _session = session;
        }
...}
```

I'm clueless on this one.  I set this up for unit testing and anytime I add a class variable to this service, it crashes.  I can add a class variable to another services or create a service that replicates this minus the interface and it works.  Any ideas?

Session Service Construct:

```
   public class SessionService: ISessionService 
    {
        private IMembershipService _membershipService;
        private IVolunteerService _volunteerService;
        private IMessageService _messageService;

          public SessionService() 
            : this(new AccountMembershipService(null), new VolunteerService(null), new MessageService())
        {}


          public SessionService(IMembershipService membershipservice, IVolunteerService volunteerservice, IMessageService messageservice)
        {
            _membershipService = membershipservice;
            _volunteerService = volunteerservice;
            _messageService = messageservice;
        }
```

Other Service Constructs:

private IValidationDictionary _validationDictionary;
   private IVolunteerRepository _repository;
   private IOrganizationService _orgservice;

```
public VolunteerService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary) 
    : this(validationDictionary, new VolunteerRepository(), new OrganizationService(null))
{}


public VolunteerService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary, IVolunteerRepository repository, IOrganizationService orgservice)
{
    _validationDictionary = validationDictionary;
    _repository = repository;
    _orgservice = orgservice;

}



public class AccountMembershipService : IMembershipService
{
    private readonly System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider _provider;
    private IValidationDictionary _validationDictionary;
    private IVolunteerService _volservice;
    private IEmailService _emailservice;

    public AccountMembershipService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
        : this(validationDictionary, null, new VolunteerService(null), new EmailService())
    {
    }

   public AccountMembershipService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary, System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider provider, VolunteerService volservice, EmailService emailservice )
    {
        _validationDictionary = validationDictionary;
        _provider = provider ?? Membership.Provider;
       _volservice = volservice;
       _emailservice = emailservice;
    }
```

Comment: What is happening in `SessionService`'s constructor?

Comment: Added service construct to question.

Comment: If you will post all the constructors of all objects created by `SessoinService` I believe you will find the issue :)

Comment: Thanks for the time.  I posted the other constructs.  I think I see the issue, the organization service constructs session which constructs volunteer which constructs organization, creating a endless loop.  Thoughts?

Comment: I removed the volunteer construct from session and the issue remains.

Comment: See my answer for more detailed description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the set of objects recursively.

Your code "smells" with [test logic in production](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html) because you create all the objects implicitly.

Instead I would encourage to use dependency injection or other [solutions](http://xunitpatterns.com/substitutable%20dependency.html) so that you do not have hard dependencies in your constructors.

In the **worst-case scenario**, just use **ServiceLocator** pattern.

The last option is the easiest way to go for you as you already have too much stuff bound together. Your code would look like this:

```
   public class OrganizationService : IOrganizationService
    {

        private IValidationDictionary _validationDictionary;
        private IOrganizationRepository _repository;

        public OrganizationService() {
            _validationDictionary = ServiceLocator.Get<IValidationDictionary>();
            _repository = ServiceLocator.Get<IOrganizationRepository>();
        }
    }
```

Let's look at the dependency on `IOrganizationRepository` here.

We don't need to know exact type of it. So we don't care. The `ServiceLocator` is the only body that does care.

Usually it is just a static class (keep in mind multi-threading and synchronization though!).

It can be implemented like this (I don't want to point to existing implementations because it is just too simple to do):

```
public static class ServiceLocator {
    static Func<T, object> _resolver;

    public static Setup(Func<T, object> resolver) {
        _resolver = resolver;
    }

    public static TService Get<TService>() {
        if (_resolver == null) throw InvalidOperationException("Please Setup first.");
        return (TService)_resolver.Invoke(typeof(TService));
    }
}
```

Then in your test setup (probably on the base test class) just do this:

```
ServiceLocator.Setup(what => {
    if (what == typeof(IOrganizationRepository))
        return organisationRepository = organisationRepository ?? new OrganizationRepository(); // Singleton
    throw new NotSupportedException("The service cannot be resolved: " + what.Name);
});
```

In production you would instantiate it differently.

Of course it can be easier with CastleWindsor, Microsoft Unity or other dependency injection framework.

Hope that will help.